# Way to modify OrbitControls to rotate camera with right click hold, and orbit target while holding alt

Tags: three.js

I wish to modify the OrbitControls example found here (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js) to allow a user to rotate the camera using right-click-hold and while holding alt, orbit the camera about a point in front of the camera. As far as I can tell this only requires a change to the target and offset but I can't seem to get things working correctly. What is the best way to go about doing this?

What I've tried so far:

- setting a flag variable 'isOrbit' to true on alt button down and in the update function changing the target location to a certain distance in front of the camera, then on alt button up, making 'isOrbit' false making the update function return the target
- Changing the target directly on alt button-down and button-up

If you have a control scheme that works in a way similar I'd love to check it out, if not, tips would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Partial answer: if you do this: `controls.mouseButtons = { LEFT: THREE.MOUSE.RIGHT, MIDDLE: THREE.MOUSE.MIDDLE, RIGHT: THREE.MOUSE.LEFT };` then right-mouse will rotate the camera, and control+right-mouse will pan the camera. (three.js. r.97)